# cassandra database - fetch huge amount of data

Tags: performance, cassandra

Have a cassandra 2.x database where from a table I have to select some data using non primary key column which is a primary of another table using a simple where clause.
The data is used in a cache.
The problem is that the retrieval process is too slow and gets timedout using the datastax 3.x driver.
Is there any way to fetch the data without upgrading the database software or altering the existing structure of database.
I tried async fetching and pagination using datastax api - still it couldn't cope up with the volume of data and the query fails.

Answer (score 3):

Cassandra is heavily optimized for access to data by primary key - full, partial, or at least partition key.  Other access patterns require additional work.  Theoretically you can use secondary index on the corresponding column, but it's only recommended if you're searching the data in addition to having at least partition key - if you just use that column alone, it will still reach all nodes and fetch all data, so it will be much slower.  And you'll need to keep in mind other limitations, such as, cardinality of the column, etc. (you can read about that [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/dataModel.html#Checkuseofauxiliaryindexing)).

Programmatically, you can do the full scan of data as well, but it shouldn't be simple `select * from table` as it will overload coordinating node, lead to timeouts, etc. Instead it should be more sophisticated solution - it's better to perform scan by reading data from individual token ranges, sending the queries to the nodes that are keeping the corresponding ranges, and it's possible to do in parallel - this is how [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) and [DSBulk](https://github.com/datastax/dsbulk/) are working (I think that you may try to adopt pieces of DSBulk code for this task - it's possible to use it as a library).  I also have [an example of how to perform full table scan](https://github.com/alexott/cassandra-dse-playground/blob/master/driver-1.x/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/TokenRangesScan.java) using the Java driver - you can adopt this code, and replace simple counting with your filtering condition.

Comment: Hi Alex Ott, 
Thanks for your valuable suggestion.
It took some time for me to get back to the problem and test your solutions.
The token based full table scan worked for non index filters without going for other libraries.

Comment: I have one more problem with datastax driver - this time it is a simple direct query using index column in an in clause - select * from xxxTable where xxxColumn in (x1, x2, x3,...)
The values in clause are not fixed and varies with the algorithmic checks. 
But the performance difference when compared to the previous neflix driver(which i am porting to datastax) is huge - a typical query that takes 25ms using netflix astyanax driver takes almost 180ms using datastax i.e an eight fold factor slower.
Any suggestions the response time could be improved up to match that astyanax of driver ?

Comment: suggestion - don't use `IN` on the partition key column, as it will introduce an additional hop for reading data - instead issue multiple requests in parallel, using `executeAsync` and then collect data in your application...

Comment: Tried using executeAsync also. It improved the overall response time only fractionally around 5-10ms. still it was no where near the response time of astyanax driver.

Comment: are you using prepared queries? if not, then it won't help because driver doesn't know how to route queries

Comment: yep. using prepared query - executeasync without in clause with only a marginal overall improvement.

Comment: It’s hard to say - too many unknowns... it’s better to ask as a separate question, with tracing, version information, etc.

Comment: ok. i will open a separate post with better clarity.

Comment: I had posted the question with more details on

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63705671/cassandra-database-fetch-time-is-higher-than-netflix-astyanax-driver-than-data