# cassandra database - fetch time is higher than Netflix Astyanax Driver than datastax driver

Tags: datastax, cassandra-2.0

We are migrating from Netflix Astyanax to Datastax driver - the details are given below

Drivers Used: 
**astyanax-cassandra (by Netflix) ; version 1.56.37


datastax-driver-core; version 3.3.2**

Java version: jdk 1.8 
Servlet Container: Jetty 9.x 
Cassandra version: 2.0.9

sample functional code:
From UUID list it filters and fetches the data from cassandra db using an in clause.

```
 public boolean isColumnIdExists(List<UUID> attrList) { 
        boolean IdExists = true;        
        try {
            
            Statement SEARCH_CQL = null;
             {              
                        // Build the statement with in clause using either of these 
                        QueryBuilder api or 
                        Prepared statment or
                        netflix api 
                        //

            } 
            final ResultSet resultSet = CassandraConnectUtil.getSession().execute(SEARCH_CQL);          
            
            for (Row row : asIterable(resultSet.iterator())) {              
                if (row.getTimestamp("deletedbytimestamp") == null) {                   
                    IdExists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new Exception("Exception", ex);
        }
        return IdExists;
    }
```

When the above piece of code is executed the response time of fetching the results take approx around 25ms using Netflix Astyanax driver while the Datastax driver responds in around 500ms.
There is a wide difference in fetch time of the different drivers.
Is there a way to improve the performance in the aforementioned datastax version.

Comment: it's hard to answer without knowing more - how many nodes in the cluster, what is the topology, what is consistency level used for requests, ...

Answer (score 1):

We don't know what is happening in `getSession`, but is it possible it's connecting a session the first time it's called?

Make sure you're following [best practices](https://docs.datastax.com/en/devapp/doc/devapp/driversBestPractices.html#Useasinglesessionobjectperapplication) of initializing a session at application startup, and using a single instance for the lifetime of the application.

Comment: The getSession function obtains the session from the following implementation

Cluster.Builder clusterBuilder = Cluster.builder().withLoadBalancingPolicy(loadBalancingPolicy);
     
clusterBuilder.withPort(cassandraPort)
                .addContactPoints(contactPoints)     

username = "xxxxx"; 
password = "xxxxx"; 
                    
cluster = clusterBuilder.withCredentials(username, password).build();
session = cluster.connect(keyspaceName);

Comment: what is in the load balancing policy?

Comment: DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy is used for load balancing.